# Email address captured through Mobile Connect is missing '@' sign , has anyone encountered this issue?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

Send a text to capture the emailaddress and wrote the user response received into DE (smsprofilecapture) and found something like user12345gmail.com instead of user1234@gmail.com. Any ideas why this happened !

```
%%[
VAR @msg,@email
SET @email = [MSG(0).NOUN(0)]
IF IsEmailAddress(@email) == ‘true’ THEN
    UpsertData('SMSProfileCapture', 1, 'MobilePhone', MOBILE_NUMBER, 'EmailAddress', @email)
    
    SET @msg = "Thank you for your information."

ELSE
    SetSmsConversationNextKeyword("9XXXX",MOBILE_NUMBER,"GETEMAIL","MOBILECONNECT")
    set @msg = "Sorry, that doesn’t seem right. Please try again. What is your email address?
    Text HELP for help. Text STOP to stop."
ENDIF
]%%
%%=v(@msg)=%%
```